# Receive message from device via socket C++

Tags: c++, sockets, wifi

I have read a lot of articles and questions about socket programming but I don't get one thing.

Imagine I have some wi-fi network, and some device connected to that wi-fi network. I send some message to the device over the wifi network, the device get's it (sure thing) and sends something to a server and I want to read (receive) that message and send it somewhere else, or even just std::cout it. How should I connect, and receive it because I don't really know how.

To better explain it:

> A - device connected to wifi (device has got some IP address)
>
> B - app that sends message to A
>
> C - server that listens and receives messages
>   that device A sends

And my question is, if B connects to A and sends something that A got, how should C get that what A give's away.

Comment: Presumably, A would connect to C and send a message to it; just like B sends to A. Are you asking how to implement a server that accepts incoming connections? I imagine there's like a million examples of that, one search away.

Comment: Not really, I know how to connect or accept connection, but I want understand how server C can listen on some IP and PORT that device has.

I mean device let say smarthpone or something like that, is connected to wifi network and has some IP PORT, and if I send msg to it from client program, and phone sends something back/away so I want to std::cout it from (C) server app to console. Something like that.

Comment: So you are asking how to eavesdrop on a private connection between two hosts you don't control. I don't know, nor do I care to find out. You might have better luck in some hacker community forums, or something.

Comment: It appears a large part of the problem is because you're mixing concepts. "A" is a TCP/IP host (computer), "B" is an app running on some host (but not running on host A?). B cannot send a TCP message to A, it has to send a message to an app running on A. "C" is even more confused; do you mean the server computer or an a program on that server?

Comment: So You guys mean, that I cannot create server that listen on some port, and echo everything that goes through this connection?

Comment: You can of course create a server that listens on some port at the IP address *of that server*, and reads data sent *to that server*. You cannot, using "normal" programming techniques, have that server listen to data exchanged between two unrelated hosts (what's called "eavesdropping"). It's possible in principle if the connection is not properly secured, but a) I don't know how, b) it's not something described in the normal engineering documentation (though I'm sure the information is out there if you care to look for it), c) it could be a crime in some jurisdictions (I am not a lawyer).

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you Igor for letting me understand this. 
To make it absolutely clear, and close this topic.
If I want to received message (now : B -> A and A -> B)
I have to send(socket, ....)
and to recv(socket, .....) /*the same socket of course, right?*/
Thanks for the answers

Comment: Of course, on a WiFi, you could sniff all unencrypted TCP traffic intended for a specific host IP/TCP port.

Comment: I assume the item 'C' in your question has *nothing* to do with the language C?

Answer (score 1):

To answer this part of the question "How should I connect, and receive it because I don't really know how?"...

Take a look at [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html) and [boost::beast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html). Lots of functionality here. Should be able to do whatever you want with the socket and talking to other devices over the network.

To answer the second part of the question...

"
A - device connected to wifi (device has got some IP address)

B - app that sends message to A

C - server that listens and receives messages that device A sends

And my question is, if B connects to A and sends something that A got, how should C get that what A give's away."

I'm a little confused as to what you mean here.

If C is the intermediary, that's easy. C receives whatever packets contain the message from B, reads, and then reroutes them (or duplicates what is necessary and sends it to B).

Also, here's [a good resource](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~chase/cps196/slides/sockets.pdf) from Duke on how this all works.
[How to do this without boost](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13071/Programming-Windows-TCP-Sockets-in-C-for-the-Begin). [More info on doing this without boost](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/52724/). Google is your friend :).